# Openshift V3: creation of mysql pod fails

Tags: mysql, openshift-origin

i'm trying to simply create an Openshift V3 Mysql 5.6 pod. I add it through the web interface and I get the following error:

> --> Scaling database-1 to 1
>   --> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in deployment database-1 to become ready
>   W0228 08:05:35.215315       1 reflector.go:330] github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/strategy/support/lifecycle.go:468: watch of *api.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 929688371 (929707349)
>   error: update acceptor rejected database-1: pods for deployment "database-1" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready

I created successfully a wildfly instance and checked in some Java code. My website is running now without a problem. I would like to add a database now but I tried several times with different database names but no luck. I always fill in database name, user name and password...

Anybody knows what the error message means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed by not changing the service name in the creation page!

Apparently when you change the "Database Service Name" to something custom I get this error... I just leave it to 'mysql' and the pod was created...